# Opencart: How to return the value based on checkbox state?

Tags: php, opencart

Want to add some fees to the Total if the checkbox is checked in opencart checkout page

Following is the code that I want to change. This code adds the fees if the Payment method "COD" is selected.

```
<?php
class ModelExtensionTotalCashonDeliveryFee extends Model {
    public function getTotal($total) {
        if ($this->config->get('cashon_delivery_fee_status') && isset($this->session->data['payment_method']) && $this->session->data['payment_method']['code'] == 'cod') {

            $this->load->language('extension/total/cashon_delivery_fee');

            $fee_amount = 0;

            $sub_total = $this->cart->getSubTotal();

            if($this->config->get('cashon_delivery_fee_type') == 'P') {
                $fee_amount = round((($sub_total * $this->config->get('cashon_delivery_fee_fee')) / 100), 2);
            } else {
                $fee_amount = $this->config->get('cashon_delivery_fee_fee');
            }

            $tax_rates = $this->tax->getRates($fee_amount, $this->config->get('cashon_delivery_fee_tax_class_id'));

            foreach ($tax_rates as $tax_rate) {
                if (!isset($taxes[$tax_rate['tax_rate_id']])) {
                    $taxes[$tax_rate['tax_rate_id']] = $tax_rate['amount'];
                } else {
                    $taxes[$tax_rate['tax_rate_id']] += $tax_rate['amount'];
                }
            }


            $total['totals'][] = array(
                'code'       => 'cashon_delivery_fee',
                'title'      => $this->language->get('text_cashon_delivery_fee'),
                'value'      => $fee_amount,
                'sort_order' => $this->config->get('cashon_delivery_fee_sort_order')
            );

            $total['total'] += $fee_amount;
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to add fees when input checkbox is checked `<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">COD Charges` in .tpl
and not when the Payment method "cod" is selected.

Answer (score 0):

you can not directly add data to model file by clicking checkbox. First you need invoke this data something like this:
In template file where checkbox will be placed to checkbox tag add `id="{{ order_id }}`
Than in to this template file or additional  javascript file add this script:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById(product_id);
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {
            addFee(product_id);
    //another stuff if you need     
}
```

Next you need in your corresponding controller file create function for example `add_fee` where you can invoke data from DB according posted `product_id` and also include this data to the current session like this `$this->session->data['fee'] = $some_fee_from_DB`.
In corresponding template file or additional javascript file add ajax function for example `addFee` :

```
function addFee(product_id) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'index.php?route=link_to_your_function/add_fee',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {

            $('#fee').html(json['fee']); // and all other data which will be returned.
                if (json['success']) {

                //some stuff on success what you need to be displayed or filled up to the corresponding fields.

                }

        }
    });
}
```

Than you will be able retrieve data in your mentioned model file, using `$this->session->data['fee']`. Here is not complete stuff, just only the way what you need to do.

Comment: Actually I am using whole module in admin panel for this. The fee is predefined there. It works perfectly when COD option selected.  I just want to pass the condition ` if ($this->config->get('cashon_delivery_fee_status') && isset($this->session->data['payment_method']) && $this->session->data['payment_method']['code'] == 'cod') {` as TRUE when checkbox is clicked.